# Retrieve a particular portion of data from pdf

Tags: java, extract

I need to retrieve some keyword related data from a pdf file. These are the keywords:Title,Scope of pdf,who proposed that pdf,version,summary,state,regulator.

Is there any tool to retrieve data from pdf?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PDFBox from Apache](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) , honestly speaking i have never used it but read lot about it on the forums.

Other alternative can be [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [JPedal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPedal).

If you are interested you can give a try with those , but I am confident that with PDFBox you will be able to meet your requirements.

Thanks

Comment: I want to retrieve content related data with content ...like title contain title name and so on ...here i want to extract title and title name.I'll give only title it should retrieve title name for all pdf's

Comment: Remaining all data no need what ever keywords i passed that data only i want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html)

Extract text from PDF and then parse it to get information you want. It is free.

Also there's another tool, [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) but if you are working on a commercial project you need to buy a license on iText.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDFBOX](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

```
public class PDFTextReader
{
   static String pdftoText(String fileName) {
        PDFParser parser;
        String parsedText = null;
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            // pdfStripper.setParagraphStart(FIND_START_VALUE);
            // pdfStripper.setParagraphEnd("FIND_END_VALUE);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cosDoc != null)
                    cosDoc.close();
                if (pdDoc != null)
                    pdDoc.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return parsedText;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println(pdftoText(FILEPATH));
    } 
}
```

Here i tried this to extract the portion. This may help you.

Comment: Thank Q ...this program i already did.. It will convert total pdf file to text data i dont want like this Actual my requirement is i'l pass some keywords like title/summary/date and so on it should retrieve title of the pdf and what summary it have and date of pdf like this.....

Comment: you can extract the particular portion from the PDF and then use your key to extract the values.

Comment: Remaining all data no need what ever keywords i passed that data only i want.

Comment: use the setParagraphStart() and setparagraphEnd() it will return the string. Then use StringUtils or normal parsing to extract the values.